# comments not appear in my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

why comments isn't appear on my theme although I confirmed showing comments! can anyone help please

these are screenshots

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjUt5PVIDDuklSRItYU-MAfSzP7?e=2tUhsi

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjUt5PVIDDuklV3poojMWiK6lAG?e=3nnult

this is my single post page

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            if(have_posts()){
                while(have_posts()){
                    the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="post p-3 m-3 bg-light">
                            <?php edit_post_link('<span class="float-right">Edit <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span>'); ?>
                            <h3>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                    <?php the_title() ?>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                            <small class="post-author text-secondary mx-2"><i class='fa fa-user mx-1'></i><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>
                            <small class="post-date text-secondary mx-2"><i class="fa fa-calendar mx-1"></i><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></small>
                            <small class="post-comments text-secondary mx-2"><i class="fa fa-comments mx-1"></i><?php comments_popup_link('no comments', 'one comment', '% comments', 'comment-url', 'commenting is disabled'); ?></small>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('', ['class' => 'img-fluid img-thumbnail d-block']); ?>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <hr>
                            <span class='post-tags'>
                                <i class='fa fa-tags'></i>
                                <?php the_category(', ') ?>
                            </span>
                            <span class='d-block'>
                                <?php
                                    if(has_tag()){
                                        the_tags();
                                    } else{
                                        echo 'Tags: no Tags';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
            echo'<div class="post-pagination py-3 my-2 mx-auto">';
                echo '<span class="mx-3">';
                    previous_post_link();
                echo '</span>';
                echo '<span class="mx-3">';
                    next_post_link();
                echo '</span>';
                echo '</div>';
                ?>
        </div>
        <?php
            echo '<hr>';
            comments_template('/comments.php',true);
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/` from comments_template string?

Comment: when I remove `/` a notice appeared telling me "Theme without comments.php is deprecated since version 3.0.0 "

Comment: Is that a custom comments template file? Usually just the function `comments_template()` should load the comments fine.